# How to zip file in .gz format in s3 bucket using java,aws-lamda

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am using AWS Toolkit plugin in eclipse to write the code and i am deploying it into aws lamda. I need to zip files in .gz format in s3 bucket of aws. Any suggestion to achieve this. Without using aws cli option.Thanks in advance.

Comment: We need some more details.  Are you receiving a Zip file and want to save as a GZip file?  How big are the files?  How big is your Lambda?  What code have you written?  Are you familiar with [ZipInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipInputStream.html) and [GZipOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html)?

Comment: Yes i am using GZipOutputStream to write the .gz file to s3 bucket. I am using S3Event to get the key and bucket . But while writing the  i am using GZIPOutputStream.                                 
GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myfolder/example.gz")); And files size is not more than 20 mb max. But got the java.io.FileNotFoundException: myfolder/example.gz (No such file or directory) exception.

Answer (score 0):

All Lambda environments get 500MB of disk space.  This is accessible in the `/tmp` directory.  You can't just write to anywhere on the disk.

So in your example you'll need to do:

```
GZIPOutputStream gzos = new GZIPOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("/tmp/example.gz"));
```

If you really need it in a folder under `/tmp` then you'll first need to create the directory you could use something like:

```
Path outputPath = Files.createDirectories(Paths.get("/tmp/myfolder"));
```

to create the subdirectory under `/tmp`.